# In React native 'adb' is not recognized as an internal and external command

Tags: android, react-native, adb, android-sdk-tools

I tried to set the path in environmental variables but it doesn't work.

Error like as below:
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.Starting the app (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tool
s/adb shell am start -n com.demo/com.demo.MainActivity...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.demo/.MainActivity }

Answer (score 19):

First of all you have to set environment variable of your android sdk's platform-tool

**Start > Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables...**

In this Environment Variables window, in the **User variables section** for (your-username) **highlight Path and click Edit...**

add this path:  **C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;**

its a default sdk path in windows OS. if you have different location than add your sdk path, than click **OK** until environment variable popup close.

If you already have a Command Prompt window open, close it then re-open and the adb devices command should then work.

**Step 2 :**

if its still not work than add **local.properties** file to your project

1. Go to your React native Project -> Android
2. Create a file local.properties
3. Open the file
4. paste your Android SDK path like below

   in Windows `sdk.dir = C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk`

   in macOS `sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk`

   in linux `sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk`

   Replace USERNAME with your user name

Now, Run `react-native run-android` in your terminal

Comment: in my case I only add ```C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk``` on path environment variable